# How to show that $\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \exp(x_1) + \exp(x_2) \leq c\}$ is unbounded if $c > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

Define $f(x) := \exp(x_1) + \exp(x_2) $

Let the sublevel set be given by $\{x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \exp(x_1) + \exp(x_2) \leq c\}$

A plot of this function along with its contour is given as:
[image]

Clearly, the sublevel sets are unbounded for every $c>0$. But how do you prove this?

I am thinking let $x_2 = x_1 + a, a \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have $ \exp(x_1) + \exp(x_2) \leq c \implies \exp(x_1)(1+\exp(a)) \leq c \implies \exp(x_1) \leq k = \frac{c}{1+\exp(a)}$ and the latter inequality is satisfied by an uncountably many $x_1$, this way we cannot place a ball large enough to contain this set. But then this is only on one line (<- never mind). Very rough arguments here.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the points lie on a line; you've shown that there is an unbounded set of points in the set, so you're done. Actually, being uncountable isn't important, really the unboundedness is the important bit.

Comment: That is, for $c>0$. For $c\le 0$ the set is empty hence bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since  $\lim_{x\to -\infty} e^x =0$ it follows that for any $\frac{c}{2} \in \mathbb {R}^+$ there is some $a$ such that $e^x\leq \frac{c}{2}$ for all $x<a$ so $e^x + e^y \leq c$ for $x<a$ and $y<a$

This implies that the sublevel set $f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ contains the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb {R}^2|x<a , y<a\}$ which is unbounded so $f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ is unbounded.

Comment: I've assumed you can prove that the infinite rectangle  $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb {R}^2|x<a , y<a\}$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Take just one exponential. Do you see that the set $e^x\le c$ is unbounded for all $c>0$? Use the same idea for several variables.

[image]

Proof: the exponential function is increasing, i.e. for any $x'\le x$ we have $e^{x'}\le e^x$. Hence,
$$
e^{x_1'}+e^{x_2'}\le e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}\le c
$$
is satisfied whenever $x_1'\le x_1$ and $x_2'\le x_2$ for $(x_1,x_2)$ in the set. It makes it possible for $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ to go to $-\infty$ within the set, hence, it is unbounded.

Comment: Provided the set is not empty.

Comment: @Did It is the assumption in OP that $c>0$.

Comment: i know -- simply add the explanation to your post.